# Does Spring provide a class to measure performance of iterative code?

Tags: java, spring, perf4j

I need to measure performances on a specific part of my application.
To calculate these measures, I use the Spring [`StopWatch`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html) class.
In a method, there is a loop where I need to measure the execution of each iteration.

What I would like is to have, for the loop part, a counter, and the min / max / average values.
Unfortunately, Spring `StopWatch` class does not provides such feature.

For example, the following code:

```
StopWatch watch = new StopWatch("foo");
watch.start("First process");
doSomething();
watch.stop();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    watch.start("loop");
    doAnotherThing();
    watch.stop();
}
System.out.println(watch.prettyPrint());
```

will output:

```
StopWatch 'foo': running time (millis) = 1469
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
01000  068%  First process
00078  005%  loop
00000  000%  loop
00016  001%  loop
00047  003%  loop
00015  001%  loop
00047  003%  loop
00094  006%  loop
00000  000%  loop
00109  007%  loop
00063  004%  loop
```

What I want is to have:

```
StopWatch 'foo': running time (millis) = 1469
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
01000  068%  First process
00469  032%  loop | min: 0 ; max: 109 ; average: 47 ; count: 10
```

Is there a way to achieve that using Spring?

ps: I know that [perf4j](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/) will allow that, but if I can avoid adding a new library, it would be great...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such class in Spring

I'd encapsulate into your own class if you'd prefer not to add Perf4J.

A general Statistics class is a handy thing to have.  Just be sure to make it thread safe.